# Python BitTorrent Library

Tags: python, bittorrent

Is there a Python BitTorrent library that *just works*?

I need to tinker around with BitTorrent protocol for a research project and I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write my own implementation of the protocol (and neither I am capable of doing so)

I looked at the sources for the official BitTorrent client, but that is not what I am looking for. A library/  module is what I would prefer.

Thanks!

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843978/nice-bittorrent-tracker-api/6857129#6857129

Comment: Checkout this version. Pure python running with Twister. this is a [Fork of ABTorrent](https://github.com/joshsziegler/AutonomoTorrent), a minimal, pure python BitTorrent client implementation using Twisted.

Comment: [github](https://github.com/search?q=bittorrent+language%3APython&ref=opensearch&type=repositories&p=1&l=Python) has some pure python bittorrent clients. https://github.com/borzunov/bit-torrent https://github.com/gallexis/pytorrent https://github.com/kishanpatel22/bittorrent https://github.com/santazhang/BitTorrent-5.3-GPL https://github.com/alal4465/BitTorrent-Client https://github.com/yamatt/python-pythorrent https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [python-libtorrent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libtorrent) project. It's a wrapper around the [libtorrent](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/index.html) C++ library, which claims to be efficient and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a pure Python project available? Note that I need this to be as easy as possible. I just checked out the project and compiled it, but I don't expect/ don't want the end user to do all this. A pure Python implementation would be perfect in case you know about it.

Comment: @Ravi, sorry, I don't know of any pure python implementation besides the "official" client.

Answer (score 13):

[BitTornado](http://www.bittornado.com/) is pure Python library written by [John Hoffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTornado).

Comment: python-libtorrent is better that BitTornado

Comment: Its not better if the developer is after a pure python solution however.