# bittorrent tracker server for private file transfer - python

Tags: python, p2p, file-transfer, bittorrent

We have a client/server application that needs to transfer the same large files to, sometimes, many different clients.

At first all is being done the most obvious way, serving the file from the webserver api where the clients send their requests to, but everything is done manually.

A great way to dramatically improve error redundancy, and transfer speed would be to use a peer-to-peer protocol such as bittorrent.

Due to deadline constraints though I can't spend too much time on the trial/error process.

I can't find any simple tracker implementation that is easily integrated to our python api.

Does anybody know of any up to date bittorrent tracker that is simple enough to just work without all whistles and bells?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python BitTorrent Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418157/python-bittorrent-library)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going with XBT, looks simple enough and is working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a open-source tracker written in python,
https://github.com/JosephSalisbury/python-bittorrent

According to author, all you need to do is:

```
from bittorrent import Tracker
tracker = Tracker()
tracker.run()
```

Just for information here is the list of few open-source trackers,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_tracker_software

The Pirate Bay (World's largest tracker) use Opentracker software,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opentracker